# how to compute the expectation of the sum of waitting times of poisson process $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t}f(S_k)]$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

In short , I don't understand the step 2 of the answer:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{N_t}f(S_k)\right]
 &= \sum_{n\ge 0}
    \mathbb{E}\left[
        \left.\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(S_k)\right|N_t=n
              \right] P(N_t=n)\\
 &= \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{n}{t}
                  \int_0^t f(x)dx \frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda t}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $f$ is a continuous real valued function, $N_t$ is a Poisson process, $S_k$ is the waiting times for $N_t$'s $k^{th}$ jump.

The step 2 of the answer implies that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(S_k)\right]=\frac{n}{t}\int_0^t f(x)dx,
$$
which is my confusing place, how does it come?

Furthermore, the aforementioned formula may implies $\mathbb{E}[f(S_k)]=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}f(x)dx$, how does it come?

Does it mean that the pdf of $S_k$ is $\frac{1}{t}$? how to get this result?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/413740/355568.                This will help.